# Creating flash 3D Carousel menu

Tags: flash, menu, carousel

Hi I have small problem related to flash and action script.

My client want me to create 3D carousel in flash. It need to rotate (one way is enough) on ellipse path, get some on mouse over effect and mouse important thing: Images need to be loaded in sequence... First image rotating, then second image is appearing (in background) when first is in front. 
Till now I was using ultimate-3d-carousel (as2) from oxylus-development (http://www.oxylusflash.com/flashfiles/ultimate-3d-carousel-as2) but I completely don't know how to load images in sequence like above...

Maybe anyone know script/tutorial/tips how to do that kind of flash carousel? My AS skills are very limited...

Or maybe anyone know how to modify existing script (I got sources)
I believe this is part of oxylus carousel witch have to be modified:

```
//loading picture to slideshow and configure it's parametters
function addPicture(nume,des,nm,par)
{
    nrp++;
    var mc=poze.attachMovie("holder","img"+nrp,poze.getNextHighestDepth());
    mc.canDraw=false;
    mc.des=des;
    mc.nm=nm;
    mc.par=par;
    mc._dx=0;
    mc._dy=0;
    mc.effSat=1;
    mc.effDark=1;
    mc.effAlpha=100;
    mc.effBlur=0;
    var mclListener:Object = new Object();
    var image_mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
    image_mcl.addListener(mclListener);
    mc.holder_son.forceSmoothing=true;
    mc.cacheAsBitmap=true;
    image_mcl.loadClip(picturePath+nume,mc.holder_son);
    mc.anim._x=0;
    mc.anim._y=0;
    mclListener.onLoadInit = function(target_mc:MovieClip) 
    {
        mc.holder_son._alpha=0;
        var mc=target_mc;
        mc.forceSmoothing=true;
        mc.cacheAsBitmap=true;
        mc._rotation=-0;
        mc._width=fixWi;
        mc._height=fixHe;
        mc._x=-mc._width/2;
        mc._y=-mc._height/2;
        mc.ct=1;

        var mc2=mc._parent.attachMovie("holder","refl",mc._parent.getNextHighestDepth());
        mc2.anim.swapDepths(mc2.getNextHighestDepth());
        removeMovieClip(mc2.anim);
        var image_mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
        image_mcl.loadClip(picturePath+nume,mc2.holder_son);
        image_mcl.addListener(mclListener);
        image_mcl.loadClip(picturePath+nume,mc.holder_son);
        mclListener.onLoadInit = function(target_mc:MovieClip) 
    {
        var mc=target_mc;
        mc.forceSmoothing=true;
        mc.cacheAsBitmap=true;
        var mcp=target_mc._parent;

        mc._width=fixWi;
        mc._height=fixHe;
        mc._rotation=-0;
        mc._x=-mc._width/2;
        mcp._alpha=100;
        var mc5=mcp.createEmptyMovieClip("desen",mcp.getNextHighestDepth());
        var mc3=mc._parent._parent.attachMovie("hMaska","hMaska",mc._parent._parent.getNextHighestDepth());


        mc3._width=fixWi+strokeSize;
        mc3._height=fixHe;
        mc3._rotation=-0;
        mc3._x=-mc._width/2-strokeSize/2;
        mc._parent._y=-fixHe/2;
        mc._yscale=-100;
        mc._y=fixHe*2;
        var mcX=mc._parent;
        mcX.cacheAsBitmap=true;
        mc3.cacheAsBitmap=true;
        mc._parent.swapDepths(mc2._parent.holder_son)
        mc.swapDepths(target_mc._parent.desen);
        mcX.setMask(mc3);
        mc3._y=fixHe/2;
        mc2._y=-fixHe+fixHe/4;
        mcX._alpha=0;
        mc._parent._parent.canDraw=true;
        if (nrp>1)poze._visible=true;
        var an=mc._parent._parent.anim;
        an._width=fixHe;
        an._height=fixHe;
        an.onEnterFrame=function()
        {
            this._alpha-=5;
            if (enRefl) 
            {
                mcX._alpha+=5;
                if (mcX._alpha>reflAlpha*2) mcX._alpha=reflAlpha*2;
            }
            else
            {
                mcX._alpha=100;
                mcX._visible=false;
            }
            mcX._parent.holder_son._alpha+=5;
            if (this._alpha<=0)
            {
                delete this.onEnterFrame
                removeMovieClip(this);
            }
        }

    }
    };
    mc.sc2=0;
    mc.gl=0;
    mc.attachMovie("mcToolTip","tt",mc.getNextHighestDepth());

    mc.onPress=function()
    {
        if(selCol!="")
        {
            if (this.par=="action")
            {
                pictureClick(this.nm);
            }
            else
            {
                getURL(this.nm,this.par);
            }
        }
    }

}


function refresh()
{
    slider._y=depY;
    mcArrows._y=depY;
    clicker._y=depY;

if (!enWheel) extraScale=0;

poze.mcLogo2.mcLogo._rotation=0;

this.poze._rotation=rotAngle;
offGuideY=fixHe;

poze.mcLogo2._alpha=logoAlpha;
poze.mcLogo2.mcLogo._width=logoWidth;
poze.mcLogo2.mcLogo._height=logoHeight;

poze.mcLogo2.mcLogo._x=-logoWidth/2;
poze.mcLogo2.mcLogo._y=-logoHeight/2;

poze.mcLogo2._rotation=-rotAngle;


poze.mcLogo2._visible=showLogo;


guide._x=poze._x-poze._width/2-offGuide/2;
guide._height=poze._height+offGuideY;
guide._width=poze._width+offGuide;
guide._y=-elev/2+spir*nrp/2;
var col=guide.hitTest(_xmouse+this._x,_ymouse+this._y,false)

var semnRot=1;
if (rotLeft==2) semnRot=-1;

if (!enSemnRot) semnRot=1;
else
{
    col=true;
}
if(!canRoll) col=false;

if (rotType==1)
{
    enSemnRot=false;
    mcArrows._visible=false;
    clicker._visible=false;
    slider._visible=false;
}

if (rotType==2) 
{
    enSemnRot=false;
    col=false;
    if (!goToStart)
    mcArrows._visible=true;
    clicker._visible=false;
    slider._visible=false;
    if (_root.selAr!=0)
    {
        spEase+=easeAm/100;
        if (spEase>=factSpeed/5) spEase=factSpeed/5;

        if (easeAm>=50)
        {
            spEase=factSpeed/5;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        spEase-=easeAm/100;
        if (spEase<=0) spEase=0;
        if (easeAm>=50)
        {
            spEase=0;
        }
    }
    cam.rot.y+=spEase*_root.selSemn;
}

if (rotType==3) 
{
    enSemnRot=false;
    col=false;
    mcArrows._visible=false;
    clicker._visible=false;
    slider._visible=true;
}

if (rotType==4) 
{
    enSemnRot=false;
    col=false;
    mcArrows._visible=false;
    clicker._visible=true;
    slider._visible=false;
    clicker.btnPrev._visible=showClickerArr;
    clicker.btnNext._visible=showClickerArr;
    if (clickerAutoPlay)
    {
        if (clickerCanAuto)
        {
            clickerAutoCrrTimer++;
            if (clickerAutoCrrTimer==clickerAutoMaxTimer)
            {
                disableClicker();
                clickerCanAuto=false;
                if (rotClickerLeft==1) clickerClick(++crrClick);
                if (rotClickerLeft==2) clickerClick(--crrClick);
                disableClicker();
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}

if (rotType==5) 
{
    enSemnRot=true;
    mcArrows._visible=false;
    clicker._visible=false;
    slider._visible=false;
}

if (col)
{

    if (!doStop)
    {

        var catRot=poze._xmouse*factSpeed*semnRot*0.001;
        if (enSemnRot)  catRot=factSpeed*semnRot*100*0.001;
        speed=catRot;
        cam.rot.y+=speed;
    }
}
if (goToStart)
{
    cam.rot.y=goToVal;
    var val=goToVal;
    if (val<0)
    {
        val=360-Math.abs(goToVal);
    }
    slider.gotoPosition(val,true);
}

genCol=false;

selCol="";
for (var i=1;i<=nrp;i++)
{
    var mc=poze["img"+i];
    mc.holder_son._width=fixWi;
    mc.holder_son._height=fixHe;
    mc.holder_son._x=-mc.holder_son._width/2;
    mc.holder_son._y=-mc.holder_son._height/2;
    mc.refl.holder_son._width=fixWi;
    mc.refl.holder_son._height=fixHe;
    mc.refl.holder_son._y=-fixHe+fixHe/2-fixHe;
    mc.refl._yscale=-100;
    mc.refl.holder_son._x=-fixWi/2;
    mc.refl._y=reflDist;
    var col=mc.holder_son.hitTest(_xmouse+this._x,_ymouse+this._y,false)

    mc.isRoll=false;
    if(!canRoll) col=false;
    if (!genCol)
    {
    mc.useHandCursor=false;
    if (col && mc.enabled)
    {

        genCol=true
        mc.isRoll=true;
        selCol=mc;
        mc.useHandCursor=true;
        mcTooltip.mcttText.scris.autoSize=true;
        mcTooltip.mcttText._x=depTooltip/2;
        mcTooltip.mcttText.scris.text=mc.des;
        mcTooltip.bgr.bgr_son._width=mcTooltip.mcttText._width+depTooltip;
        mcTooltip.bgr.sageata._x=mcTooltip.bgr._width/2-mcTooltip.bgr.sageata._width/2;
    }
    }
    mc._parent.refl._visible=false;
    mc.tt._visible=false;
    mc.tt.mcttText.scris.autoSize=true;
    mc.tt.bgr._width=mc.tt.mcttText._width+depTooltip;
    mc.tt._x=-mc.tt._width/2;
    mc.tt.mcttText._x=depTooltip/2;
    if (enTt)
    {
        mc.tt._visible=ttlAways;
        mc.tt.gotoAndStop(mcTooltip._currentframe);
        mc.tt.bgr.sageata._visible=false;
        if (ttFolMouse) selCol.tt._visible=false;
        semnTT=-1;
        if (ttFollow==2) semnTT=1;
        mc.tt._y=semnTT*fixHe/2+semnTT*mc.tt._height-strokeSize/2;
        if (semnTT==1)  mc.tt._y=fixHe/2+strokeSize;
        if (!ttlAways && !ttFolMouse) selCol.tt._visible=true;
        mc.tt.mcttText.scris.text=mc.des;
    }
}
if (genCol || enTTFromClicker!=0)
{
    mcTooltip._x=_xmouse-mcTooltip.bgr._width/2;
    mcTooltip.bgr.sageata._visible=true;
    if (enTTFromClicker)
    {
        mcTooltip.mcttText.scris.autoSize=true;
        mcTooltip.mcttText._x=depTooltip/2;
        var ttText=poze["img"+enTTFromClicker].des
        mcTooltip.mcttText.scris.text=ttText;
        mcTooltip.bgr.bgr_son._width=mcTooltip.mcttText._width+depTooltip;
        mcTooltip.bgr.sageata._x=mcTooltip.bgr._width/2-mcTooltip.bgr.sageata._width/2;

    }

    var posY=selCol._y+selCol._height;
    if (ttFollow==1)
    {
        mcTooltip.bgr.sageata._yscale=100;
        mcTooltip._y=_ymouse-mcTooltip._height/2-depToolTipY;
        if (!ttFolMouse)
        {
            mcToolTip._visible=false;
        }

    }

    if (ttFollow==2)
    {
        mcTooltip.bgr.sageata._y=0.9;
        mcTooltip.bgr.sageata._yscale=-100;
        mcTooltip._y=_ymouse+mcTooltip._height/2+depToolTipY;
        if (!ttFolMouse)
        {
            mcTooltip._x=0;
            mcTooltip._y=39;
            mcTooltip.bgr.sageata._visible=false;
        }
    }
    mcTooltip._visible=true;
    mcTooltip._visible=enTt;
    if (!ttFolMouse)
    {
        mcTooltip._visible=false;
    }
    if (enTTFromClicker) mcTooltip._visible=true;

    mcTooltip._alpha+=10;
    if (mcTooltip._alpha>=100) mcTooltip._alpha=100;
    if (enStoponRoll) doStop=true;
}
else
{
    if (enStoponRoll) doStop=false;
    mcTooltip._alpha-=10;
    if (mcTooltip._alpha<=0) 
    {
        mcTooltip._alpha=0;
        mcTooltip._visible=false;
    }
}
render();
if (_root.xmlWindow._visible) loadWindow();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

refer a this site, very awesome tutorial for you.

http://tutorials.flashmymind.com/2009/03/vertical-3d-carousel-with-actionscript-3/

Comment: Thank You for tutorial. But do You know how can I load images like I wrote on my original post? Load one in background and after it go front load another and so on?

Comment: sorry, virtually i don't know AS2. i started appeard AS3.0 ^^;
I recommend  AS3.0 to you. 
AS2.0 is not useful any more.